# Measuring execution time of a call to system() in C++

Tags: c++, linux, timing

I have found some code on measuring execution time here
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/index.php?showtopic=24685

However, it does not seem to work for calls to system(). I imagine this is because the execution jumps out of the current process.

```
clock_t begin=clock();

system(something);

clock_t end=clock();
cout<<"Execution time: "<<diffclock(end,begin)<<" s."<<endl;
```

Then

```
double diffclock(clock_t clock1,clock_t clock2)
{
    double diffticks=clock1-clock2;
    double diffms=(diffticks)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return diffms;
}
```

However this always returns 0 seconds... Is there another method that will work?

Also, this is in Linux.

Edit: Also, just to add, the execution time is in the order of hours. So accuracy is not really an issue.

Thanks!

Comment: System calls, and calls to the system() function are by no means the same thing. I've edited and retagged to reflect this.

Comment: Maybe the system call does take 0 seconds. Did you try something long on purpose?

Comment: Notice that there are two functions to measure: time taken by the process and real-time taken up. `getrusage` can measure the first in microsecond resolution. `gettimeofday` can measure the second one in microsecond resolution. If your process sleeps (waiting on input..), `getrusage` won't take that into account, it will also not take times taken up by other processes into account. So i guess if the task is I/O, you want `gettimeofday`, and if it's cpu-bound, you want `getrusage`. Not sure tho that's the right way.

Comment: Thanks! I will try these and see how they go...

Comment: Also, the execution time I am measuring is in the order of hours

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you considered using [gettimeofday](http://dell5.ma.utexas.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?gettimeofday+2)?

```
struct timeval tv;
struct timeval start_tv;

gettimeofday(&start_tv, NULL);

system(something);

double elapsed = 0.0;

gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
elapsed = (tv.tv_sec - start_tv.tv_sec) +
  (tv.tv_usec - start_tv.tv_usec) / 1000000.0;
```

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately clock() only has one second resolution on Linux (even though it returns the time in units of microseconds).

Many people use gettimeofday() for benchmarking, but that measures elapsed time - not time used by this process/thread - so isn't ideal. Obviously if your system is more or less idle and your tests are quite long then you can average the results. Normally less of a problem but still worth knowing about is that the time returned by gettimeofday() is non-monatonic - it can jump around a bit e.g. when your system first connects to an NTP time server.

The best thing to use for benchmarking is clock_gettime() with whichever option is most suitable for your task.

- CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID - Thread-specific CPU-time clock.
- CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID - High-resolution per-process timer from the CPU.
- CLOCK_MONOTONIC - Represents monotonic time since some unspecified starting point.
- CLOCK_REALTIME - System-wide realtime clock.

**NOTE** though, that not all options are supported on all Linux platforms - except clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME) which is equivalent to gettimeofday().

Useful link: [Profiling Code Using clock_gettime](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2007/09/22/profiling-code-using-clock_gettime/)

Answer (score 0):

Tuomas Pelkonen already presented the `gettimeofday` method that allows to get times with a resolution to the microsecond.

In his example he goes on to convert to double. I personally have wrapped the `timeval` struct into a class of my own that keep the counts into seconds and microseconds as integers and handle the add and minus operations correctly.

I prefer to keep integers (with exact maths) rather than get to floating points numbers and all their woes when I can.

Comment: For timing, it's really not that important to be exact. The level of jitter in most timings means that you've probably only got a few significant figures (unless the call is taking a *very* long time, in which case you could time it with a wristwatch).